# WinRT Save Config FILES

Tags: windows-runtime

I'm having a very serious problem in my application, I save the configuration files in the LocalState folder, but they are being excluded in the updates, so I changed to RoamingState and the same problem occurs, I launch an update and I have complaints about lost settings, there is a folder that persists in updates? what is the best folder to save files and not be deleted?

Comment: I'm new to the Windows Runtime, but according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData?view=winrt-19041), `Local` data types are "stored on the device, backed up in the cloud, and persists across updates".

Comment: Não está mantendo nas atualizações

Comment: English please.